# Selecting radio button in geb

Tags: geb

I have 3 radio button in a form with ID, value, and name.

With Geb CSS selector I have tired all combination to click on of the radio button but no success!!

I have tried `testBtn {$("input", ID:"resident", name:"status")}` then in spec `testBtn.value("My status")` where radio button `value="My status"`, but label next radio button is `"Status"`. Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to use the id in your selector as this would select only one radio. To mark a radio button as selected you set a value on a set of radio buttons with a given name. For your example that would be:

```
$('input', name: 'status').value('My status')
```

or if you used content DSL:

```
static content = {
    status { $('input', name: 'status') }
}

status = 'My status'
```

Please refer to the section on [selecting radio buttons](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#radio) in the Book of Geb.